# What is a regular expression and C# code to strip any html tag except links?

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, regex, sql-server-2005

I'm creating a CLR user defined function in Sql Server 2005 to do some cleaning in a lot of database tables.

The task is to remove almost all tags except links (`'a'` tags and their `'href'` attributes). So I divided the problem in two stages. 1. creating a user defined sql server function, and 2. creating a sql server script to do the update to all the involved tables calling the clr function.

For the user defined function and given the restricted environment, I prefer to do this with native libraries. That means, not using the Html Agility Pack, for example.

In javascript this regular expression, apparently does the right job:

```
 <\s*a[^>]\s*href=(.*)>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>
```

At least, according to http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

But, I don't know how to translate that (especially, the capturing groups part) into C# code to use the text as part of the output.

For instance, if the input is : `<a href="http://example.com">some text</a>`
how to save the text `"http://example.com"` and `"some text"` as part of the output in C# code and at the same time stripping any other possible html tag (and their content)?

Comment: By now you’ve received several answers, all of which had severe bugs in the regexes. I’ve commented to this effect and the authors have apparently mostly deleted their answers. Is this enough evidence for you that doing this with regular expressions is very hard to get right?

Comment: So, what else can I do for the task at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end. I made a separate .net console program combining HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) and querying SQL Server from there. In the program I did use a naive regular expression to isolate the  fragments, and with HAP I did retrieve the href and anchor texts, and with that I did a final composition stripping out any other characters except text, numbers, and some punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as bomb-proof as Jordan's, but an example using Matches instead:

```
var pattern = @"<.*href=""(?<url>.*)"".*>(?<name>.*)</a>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var groups = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", groups["url"], groups["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Consider the input: `<a href="/" title="Homepage">Homepage</a>`. Your code would claim that `Homepage` is the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is completely wrong:

```
<\s*a[^>]\s*href=(.*)>(.*?)<\s*/\s*a>
      ↑            ↑
      1.           2.
```

1. This causes `<aa...`, `<ab...`, `<ac...` etc. to match too.
2. This causes you to overmatch. For example, consider this input:

   ```
   <a href='/one'>One</a> <a href='/two'>Two</a>
           ├───────────────────────────┤ ├─┤
                      group 1            grp2
   ```